# What is difference between using "pure" String and String returned from method?

Tags: java

I'm new to programming and as I was using some strings in Java I could not figure out this probably simple question:

If we have method:

```
public static String str(String arg)
{
 return arg;
}
```

Is there any difference between those two samples below?

```
System.out.println("Hello");
```

vs

```
System.out.println(Someclass.str("Hello"));
```

What is processed faster? Is it better to set arguments of methods using return value of different method or using chosen datatype directly? Is there any practical use of second sample?

Thanks and sorry if it's dumb question.

Comment: If you're new to Java then it very likely doesn't matter whatsoever and you should use which is most readable. Aside from that: the second example, as shown, makes no sense.

Comment: not sure what your case 2 is supposed to be doing. Are you saying you have a class called Someclass which has a method str(String input) which will just return the same string it was passed ("hello" in this example) ? If so, first of all it is pointless to have a function which will do nothing but return the input that was passed into it and case1 will be marginally faster due to case 2 having to make a call to Someclass

Comment: You are passing an argument and then returning the same thing, why not use the original?

Comment: Case 2 is the same as case 1 with unecessary extra steps, so of course it's slower

Comment: There is no difference between string declared as variable and returned from method - they are Java objects of the same type. Second case is a bit slower since method call has overhead.

Comment: Only _might be_ slower. The Java compiler is pretty smart.

Comment: You might be interested in reading http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~dianeh/tutorials/params/, in particular the section on 'Passing Strings'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, except that the second example is more obfuscatory, the method call doesn't add any value. Run this code:

```
"Hello".equals(Someclass.str("Hello"));
```

It will return true, that tells you that the strings are equivalent.

All the method in the second example does is take the reference passed in and return it, so the code

```
String s = "Hello";
System.out.println(Someclass.str(s) == s);
```

will print true; s and Someclass.str's return value should be the same reference.

Don't fixate on performance, try to write code that makes sense.

Comment: Actually, because of the way that String literals work in Java, they would both be references to exactly the same string, and so == would also return true.

Comment: @Bobby: yes, that's right. didn't know if i should get into that here, though.

Comment: Trying to explain the difference between .equals and == to a novice can get tricky ;)

Answer (score 1):

The **first case** is faster.

The **second case** is nonsensical. You are passing a `String` to a method which simply returns that same `String` object. There is absolutely no reason to do this. It will probably be a bit slower because of the unnecessary method call.

Using double quotes will already automatically create a `String` object.

And in any case, *readable code far outweighs small performance boosts* in all but the most demanding scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

The **first** case is slightly faster and it makes no sense using the second one unless you are modifying the string in `Someclass`'s `str` method.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, all parameters are passed by value.  This includes references to objects like Strings.  When you call the `str(String arg)` method, you are not actually passing the String into the method, rather a copy of the reference that points to the String's location in memory.  When you return `arg`, again, you are returning a copy of this reference to the String.

In your second example you are using a String literal.  Java treats these in a special way (the compiler essentially creates a constant and substitutes that constant in place of the literal wherever you see it in code).  So when you pass the literal in, you are actually passing a copy of the reference (memory location) of the literal, and then returning it.  There is still only one String object.

In other words, all you are doing is adding a small amount of overhead by inserting the method call in the middle.